# UIAccessibilityCustomAction selector not being triggered

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility

Currently having issues getting the method in my `UIAccessibilityCustomAction` selector from being triggered. The code below lives in a custom UITableViewCell class, and is called upon cell initialization. It correctly displays the `UIAccessibilityCustomAction`, but i'm unable to perform the action on both device and Accessibility Inspector. What am i doing wrong?

```
@objc func doSomething() {
    print("something")
}

func addAccessibilityActions() {
    accessibilityCustomActions = [
        UIAccessibilityCustomAction(name: NSLocalizedString("information", comment: ""), target: self, selector: #selector(doSomething))
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

Your [custom action](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#custom-actions) is well defined in the `UIAccessibilityCustomAction` array but I think your implementation isn't correct to perform the action. Try this code snippet hereafter:

```
@objc func doSomething() -> Bool {

    //Code to be implemented for the appropriate action.
    print("something")

    return true
}
```

Besides, since iOS 13, you can use a [new syntax](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-19000.html#CustomActionsCoding) for the custom actions introducing a closure as follows:

```
accessibilityCustomActions = [
    UIAccessibilityCustomAction(name: NSLocalizedString("information", comment: ""),
                                actionHandler: {(customAction: UIAccessibilityCustomAction) -> Bool in
                                                print("something")
                                                return true})]
```